# how to find the span in protractor

Tags: protractor

i want to turn on the toggle button in protractor. below is the DOM

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="UseRecipientList" ng-model="newProduct.useRecipientList" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">
<span>
::before
::after
</span>
```

if I identify the element by xpath, it is working fine. i have used, `element(by.xpath("//input[@id='UseRecipientList']/following-sibling::span"));`

if I want to go by ng-model, how to identify the span which comes after `ng-model` as above in protractor?

Comment: I take it that interacting directly with the input is not working as you expect? `(by.id('UseRecipientList')).click()`

Comment: @DublinDev with xpath, it is working as expected; but i want to use ng-model for my protractor script; i am not sure how to do for the above dom

Answer (score 2):

Use css as below

```
const locator= element(by.css('input#UseRecipientList > span'));
```

So the above locator help you to get the span as below

```
locator.getText();
```

To inspect using model name.Try the below one.

```
var input = element(by.model('newProduct.useRecipientList'));
```

For more on ng-model refer https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.model

Hope it helps you!!

Comment: @kavitha Please mark the answer as correct if it has helped to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try with css locator

```
(by.css('[ng-model="newProduct.useRecipientList"] span'));
```